# Calculate c-hat from coxph model

Tags: cox-model, overdispersion

I am analyzing sage-grouse survival using cox proportional hazard models and need to test my global model for overdispersion by calculating a c-hat. Most people use the c_hat{AICcmodavg} function; however, this function doesn't seem to recognize the object produced by coxph models (see below). Is there any other similar functions that can produce a c-hat value for a cox's model?
Thanks,
Kyle

> KE_global <- coxph(Surv(Start, End, Event) ~ Age+Res+Sex+Year1+DDM, data = sagr)
>
> c_hat(KE_global, method = "pearson")
>
> Error in c_hat.default(KE_global, method = "pearson") :
> Function not yet defined for this object class

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, and I havn't seen overdispersion done on cox hazard models before. Perhaps it isn't very surprising that this error occurs. In the [official package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AICcmodavg/AICcmodavg.pdf#page.50) it states that:

> Functions  to  compute  an  estimate  of  c-hat  for  binomial  or  Poisson  GLM’s  and  GLMM’s  using different estimators of overdispersion.

Checking for over- or under-dispersion is usually performed when the obsereved variance is greater than expected. In [overdispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion) :

> A common task in applied statistics is choosing a parametric model to fit a given set of empirical observations. This necessitates an assessment of the fit of the chosen model.

The Cox proportional hazard model is, however, semi-parametric. More importantly, it does not assume any underlying distribution in order to fit a model. See [Cox Proportional-Hazards Regression for Survival Data / John Fox](https://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion-1E/appendix-cox-regression.pdf):

> This model is
>   semi-parametric
>   because while the baseline hazard can take any form, the covariates enter the
>   model linearly.